# How does BLE handle sending multiple packets per inteval with a 1-bit sequence number?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

As far as I unterstand BLE uses two 1-bit fields for applying sequence numbers to packets (SN, NESN). From my (admittedly basic) knowledge about (wireless) communication a 1-bit sequence number is perfectly fine as long as a sender does not continue sending data until the last message is acknowledged by the receiver.

Because of that it is trivial to understand how BLE works with a one-packet-per-interval scheme. However BLE allows multiple packets in a single connection interval. So far I couldn't find any information on how this scenario is handled without allocating more bits for larger sequence numbers.

Any pointers in the right direction on where I'm going wrong or where I can read up on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure enough about this to formulate it as a full answer, but as far as I know, multiple packets in a connection interval are always sent alternatively between client and server. There should be no situation where the server sends more than one packet without the client acknowledging it first (and vice versa). See also here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/technical-considerations

Comment: Nebr is correct

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just double-checked the specification and it was indeed a misconception on my part. I guess my problem is actually that I don't see the benefits/drawbacks of sending multiple packets in a single (long) interval vs. a single packet per interval in short connection intervals.

Comment: As the time between two connection intervals is fixed (and is defined by the connection parameters), using longer intervals leads to more time between between two connection intervals and thus to a larger reaction time. On the other hand, opening/closing a connection costs time and energy, so it is more efficient to transmit more packets per interval. The optimum is dependent on the actual devices and expected use cases.